# Joomla malicious file upload and cross site scripting

Tags: security, joomla

My site is under security audit to get the security certification. After audit they gave me two security issues to look at.

1. Stored Cross Site Scripting: The application must implement server side validation for all user-entered inputs. Only expected values should be accepted. Script tags should be rejected. All user inputs should be sanitized.
2. Malicious File Upload

I have added the  at filter tags in Joomla global configuration text filters. And also though I have clearly stated for all file upload elements to only use .jpg,.jpeg,.png extensions, I can still upload .php extension files.

How can we rectify these two issues?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use the `defines.php` file to clean the POST data before it reaches the Joomla site, and block any request with $_FILES in it.

If your website needs to allow users to upload files, then make sure that these files only consist of specific file types, and, if you don't need the external world to have access to these files, then block access to these files (in the folder you have them uploaded to) using an `htaccess` rule.